# jquery/javascript function within string concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to concatenation string having some calculated values in between, so i tried the code below:

```
var html = '<tr>' + 
          function () {
              var tds = '' 
              array.each(function (i, ele) { tds += '<td>' + i + '</td>' });
              return tds;
          } +
          '</tr>';
```

But its not working. The function i used in concatenation as treating like a string itself !. Is there any way to do that ? Thank you

Comment: You are defining function but not calling it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use an immediately-executing function:

```
var html = '<tr>' + 
      (function () {
          var tds = '' 
          array.each(function (i, ele) { tds += '<td>' + i + '</td>' });
          return tds;
      })() +
      '</tr>';
```

But you don't need this function, you can use existing functions to do what you want:

```
var html = '<tr>' + array.map(function(i, ele) {
    return '<td>' + i + '</td>';
}).join() +
    '</tr>';
```